# I want to represent django model as table in html page with table heading same as django field name. How can I implement this?

Tags: python, django, html-table

I am new to Django. I'm stuck to a problem which I feel is beyond my current abilities in Django. 
The problem is about using heading for table column same as string representation of its relative model field.To understand this further, 
assume I have a model as below:

```
class Car(models.Model):
   company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name='cars')
   transmission_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   color = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
```

For this model I want to generate HTML table as below:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Company Name</th>
       <th>Transmission Type</th>
       <th>Color</th>
       <th>Age</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>{{company_name}}</td>
           <td>{{transmission_type}}</td>
           <td>{{color}}</td>
           <td>{{age}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this in Django?

Comment: Please do *not* name a reference to a `Company` `company_name`. Use `company`. This is after all what you obtained.

Comment: You might want to consider using some existing library like [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This is not a task that hasn't been comprehensively solved before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the most important processing part in the view. For example:

```
def some_view(request):
    model = Car
    field_names = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields()]
    data = [[getattr(ins, name) for name in field_names]
            for ins in Model.objects.prefetch_related().all()]
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'field_names': field_names, 'data': data})
```

and as `some_template.html`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    {% for head in field_names %}
       <th>{{ head }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
            <td>{{ cell }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

We thus construct a 2d table for each field name and each model instance. Then we render this data in a HTML template that contains `<table>` logic.

**EDIT**: using `verbose_name`. Since the field names are sometimes a bit cryptic, we can use the `verbose_name` of the field as well:

```
def some_view(request):
    model = Car
    field_names = list(model._meta.get_fields())
    titles = [f.verbose_name for f in field_names]
    field_Names = [f.name for f in field_names]
    data = [[getattr(ins, name) for name in field_names]
            for ins in Model.objects.prefetch_related().all()]
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'field_names': titles, 'data': data})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it. It's exactly what I was looking for. The doubt is; it uses model field name as it is. What to do if field name contains underscore e.g. 'panel_color' in above example? I think we can create some filter to remove underscore though I can work around by avoiding underscores at any cost in the first place.

Comment: @ShriP: typically a field has a `verbose_name` as well, which can be specified by the user as well. So we can slightly modify it. By default `verbose_name` is the field name, but can be overwritten.