# I want to represent django QUERY as table in html page with table heading same as django field name. How can I implement this?

Tags: django, html-table, django-queryset

I would like to find a way to represent on HTML table a recordset obtained through a SQL query.
I consulted a previous post that spoke of a similar problem to mine but in that post refer to a model and I couldn't adapt it to my needs.
I would like to adapt the solution of that post so that it works even when I use SQL query.

It would be possible? The post is this:

[I want to represent django model as table in html page with table heading same as django field name. How can I implement this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264782/i-want-to-represent-django-model-as-table-in-tml-page-with-table-heading-sam-a)

**Here my view:**

```
def posts_discussione(request,pk):
discussione = Discussione.objects.get(pk=pk)
posts = Post.objects.raw(f'SELECT * from forum_post where discussione_id = {pk} order by dataCreazione ASC')
context = {'posts':posts,'discussione':discussione}
return render(request,'posts-discussione.html',context)
```

**Here my HTML code:**

```
     <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Autore</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Contenuto</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{post.autorePost}}</td>
                <td>{{post.dataCreazione}}</td>
                <td>{{post.contenuto}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you work with a Django ORM call?

Comment: Hi Willem!!Thanks for your reply. Because I don't have enough skills to make complex query with ORM call :-( Is there a way to get same result using this mode to obtain a recordset?

Comment: but this is *likely* not a complicated call, can you share the models of `Discussione` and `Post`? If this is done with a `Foreignkey`, it is quite easy, and even if the `ForeignKey` is missing, this still is feasible.

Comment: Ok  I have used this code as an example because I know that in the future I will find myself in situations where I will have to resort to queries to get a recordset.  So the templates in this view are not the ones I will need in the future.  If it is not possible to use objects.raw to get that kind of result using objects.raw we can leave this post pending and when I am ready I will share the real models.  Is it good for you? Thanks a lot for your support!!

Comment: See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields). I guess you want field instances separated right ?